# Finding data from one array by looping another array (MongoDB, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have 2 arrays.

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3]
array2 = [{id:1}, {id:1}, {id:3}]
```

I want to get an array of objects with same id. Like when I go get all the object of 1 then I will loop through array2 and get the object then put them in a 3rd array.

I'm stuck at this point.

Update:

Thanks to flyingfox for solving my issue. But I see that if i have duplicate value in array1 the array2 doenst include it multiple time.

```
let array1 = [1, 3, 3, 3]
let array2 = [{id:1}, {id:2},{id:3}]

array1 = array1.filter(e1 => array2.some(e2 => e2.id === e1))
array2 = array2.filter(e1 => array1.some(e2 => e2 === e1.id))

here array2=[{id:1}, {id:3}]
But I want to get the duplicate as well. 
Like array2=[{id:1}, {id:3}, {id:3}, {id:3}] as array1 has 3 multiple time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to put all elements with same id into a new array,then below is a reference for you

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3]
let array2 = [{id:1}, {id:1}, {id:3},{id:4}]

array1 = array1.filter(e1 => array2.some(e2 => e2.id === e1))
array2 = array2.filter(e1 => array1.some(e2 => e2 === e1.id))

let array3 = [...array1,...array2]
console.log(array3)
```

Comment: @ManasS.Roy Glad it can help you

Comment: what needs to be done to keep duplicate data inside array?

Comment: @ManasS.Roy Do not get what do you want,can you update your question or post a new question,please?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: @ManasS.Roy can you post it into a new question,please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74726922/17818994 

please check this one

Comment: @ManasS.Roy What a bad news,the new question you have posted is closed by others,but I have add an answer for it,you can check it now